# Opening urls in Avaloniaui Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui

Avalonia.Android was recently launched, for creating apps with the AvaloniaUI interface. I was in doubt: is there a way to open website links in an android application made in Avaloniaui?

I tried several ways to implement this functionality, even using Process in C#, but without success. It would be a lot of help if someone showed how to implement the url

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use Xamarin Essentials in Android projects to open URLs.